# True X/Y plot for a pandas series

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a pandas series with date/values where the dates are unevenly spaced, eg:

```
DATE
2014-12-04         0.000000
2014-12-05    250556.619700
2014-12-10    357143.631767
2014-12-20    435740.234867
...
```

I'm trying to get a true X/Y plot where the spacing of the dates is reflected on the x-axis, but I can't find an easy solution.

I could of course convert the dates into number of days from 1970 (whatever) and do an X/Y plot vs that, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Are the dates strings or Timestamp objects?

Comment: Very good question. I import the data from a CSV file and set the first column as index in the read_csv. When I when I print df.dtypes, I don't get a type for the index column.

Comment: Well if they're `Timestamp` objects then it'll do exactly what you want. So the plot will be spaced according to the difference between the dates. So I'd guess they're strings in this case.

Comment: Try adding `parse_dates=[0]` to the `pd.read_csv` command. Assuming that the dates are index 0 of course.

Comment: You should also be able to convert them using `df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])`

Comment: Ffisegydd, parse_dates=[0] worked like a charm, thanks! EdChum, df['DATE'] generates a key error, presumably because DATE is the index. But df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your dates aren't `Timestamp` objects, and are instead strings. If you convert them to `Timestamp` objects then it will plot properly, *i.e.* it'll plot unevenly for uneven date spacing.

To parse a column when using [`pd.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) you can pass the keyword argument `parse_dates=[0]` (assuming that your dates are in the 0th column).